# Cannot to create new Student in the Contoso University tutorial

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am going through the [Contoso University tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and im stacked at the second step about [CRUD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-6.0). My code is identical to template code. But when im trying to post form, nothing happens.

### Student entity:

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Razor page:

```
@page
@model ContosoUniversity.Pages.Students.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.FirstMidName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.FirstMidName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.EnrollmentDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.EnrollmentDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.EnrollmentDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

### Page model:

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Pages.Students
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SchoolContext _context;

        public CreateModel(SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Student Student { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var emptyStudent = new Student();

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Student>(
                emptyStudent,
                "student",   // Prefix for form value.
                s => s.FirstMidName, s => s.LastName, s => s.EnrollmentDate))
            {
                _context.Students.Add(emptyStudent);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

### School Context:

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Data
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext (DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        }
    }
}
```

### Dependency Injections:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'SchoolContext' not found.")));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

### Students/Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model ContosoUniversity.Pages.Students.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student[0].LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student[0].FirstMidName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student[0].EnrollmentDate)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Student) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Students/Index.cshtml.cs:

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Pages.Students
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext _context;

        public IndexModel(ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Student> Student { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Student = await _context.Students.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

### Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="row mb-auto">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row no-gutters border mb-4">
            <div class="col p-4 mb-4 ">
                <p class="card-text">
                    Contoso University is a sample application that
                    demonstrates how to use Entity Framework Core in an
                    ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web app.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row no-gutters border mb-4">
            <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                <p class="card-text mb-auto">
                    You can build the application by following the steps in a series of tutorials.
                </p>
                <p>
@*                    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro" class="stretched-link">See the tutorial</a>
*@                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row no-gutters border mb-4">
            <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column">
                <p class="card-text mb-auto">
                    You can download the completed project from GitHub.
                </p>
                <p>
@*                    <a href="https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples" class="stretched-link">See project source code</a>
*@                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

There are no occurrences here. Also i installed all required NuGet packages

### Sreenshots:

[Create Student page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zBPC.jpg)

[SSOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ytt.jpg)

[DevTools Network trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtGOM.jpg)

### DevTools errors:

[DevTools errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXPew.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your Index's code?

Comment: Something happens, you just are not observing it. Debug. Look in the browser dev tools network trace and js console. Add logging.

Comment: @QingGuo Added it to the post now

Comment: @Crowcoder thank you, i found 3 errors in js console, but i idk what is problem.
Pinned it to the post.

index.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) {message: 'The message port closed before a response was received.'}

Comment: @VladK I ran this tutorial on Edge and didn't have your problem, your problem may be a browser problem.

Comment: Debag helped me. Problem was in not nullable property Enrollments. TryUpdateModelAsync method couldnt update model cause i didnt pass Enrollments value to it. Its a little bit weird cause my code is FULLY identical to tutorial code. Just added elvis symbol to the ICollection<Enrollment> type: 
public ICollection<Enrollment>? Enrollments { get; set; }

Comment: @QingGuo thank you for trying to help. Idk why u didnt have this problem... Looks like i missed something.

Comment: @VladK 'To eliminate the warnings from nullable reference types, remove the following line from the ContosoUniversity.csproj file:' <Nullable>enable</Nullable>. Have you removed this?

Comment: @QingGuo I remember that i did this, but now I see that line. Thank you very much! Looks like it was the problem. May be i didnt save my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more detailed answer that might help others who have this issue:

The problem was that the enrollment navigation property "Enrollments" in the Student Entity

```
public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

is null when user creates a new student. This results in an invalid model state. To eliminate this issue, you can remove the line `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from the ContosoUniversity.csproj file. If you did not want to enable nullable reference types across the entire project, you could change the navigation property by adding "?" as follows:

```
public ICollection<Enrollment>? Enrollments { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that i did not remove the enable from the ContosoUniversity.csproj file

Comment: Your question is very detailed, but your answer is an off-hand remark. For the newbie that will follow us, please take a moment and show us what and where your 'remove the enable' was made.

Comment: A bit more detail was provided by @AvgSizedHead, but more completely:  c# 8 introduced null state analysis, which attempts to reduce the occurrences of NullReference exceptions.  This feature is enabled by default on new projects, and causes the problem that the OP (and I) encountered.  The csproj element "Nullable" controls this behavior Non-intuitively, Disable means to allow nulls for reference types... actually, it means to disable the new feature.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references .